# Does exporting in schema mode also exports grants?

Tags: oracle, schema, migration, export

Hi guys I a complete newbie in oracle databases and I'm just curious about when you do an export datapump in schema mode, does it also exports grants?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it exports all the objects under that schema including GRANTS also.

Answer (score 2):

You're asking lots of datapump questions - I suggest that you read [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#SUTIL864).

> If you have the DATAPUMP_EXP_FULL_DATABASE role, then you can specify
>   a list of schemas, optionally including the schema definitions
>   themselves and also system privilege grants to those schemas.